# Creating tag synonym throws an error ..in an erroneous way

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, 500-server-error

I was trying to create a synonym on [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/). Clicking the '*Create Synonym*' button threw this error:

[image: screenshot of error, showing the Tag Synonyms page, with the code of another page titled "Oops! Something Bad Happened" showing as an overlay]

It seems the '*Create tag synonym*' pop-up got replaced by the code of the (error) page I would normally (?) be redirected to:

> <!DOCTYPE html> <html class="html__responsive " lang="en">  <title>**Oops! Something Bad Happened** - Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange</title> [&c...]

It doesn't seem to matter on which tab of the [synonyms page](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) I click on the '*Create synonym*' button.

Note that the tag I wanted to create a synonym for did not yet exist (I anticipate its use).
The way the error was thrown was not caused by Dark Reader (visible in the screenshot — I mention it because it's the only plugin I have that changes the visual layout of pages in Firefox).

---

- Firefox v. 101.0.1
- Windows 10 Pro 19044.1706

Comment: Writing clear error messages is an art in itself ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I wouldn't mind taking a crack at that particular art, but I fear Arts & Crafts is not the right site to hone that skill :)

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to what happens when you click the "Create synonyms" button on the `/tags/synonyms` page itself (rather than the corresponding button in the modal dialog box that appears)?

Comment: After testing it myself (with an existing destination tag, but a source tag that didn't already exist as a tag), it looks like the initial "Create synonym" button works correctly to bring up the modal – but filling in the fields and then clicking the "Create synonym" button in the modal itself throws the error shown in your screenshot. In addition, initially suggesting a synonym from the `/tags/<tagname>/synonyms` page throws a different-looking but also problematic error (that seems to include an embedded version of the page with a red background).

Comment: @V2Blast [the synonym creation code changed recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418543/why-can-neither-mods-nor-cms-forcibly-create-synonyms-from-a-big-tag-to-a-small) perhaps that's the cause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed.

> regression error
> from the aforementioned fix
> sorry about that